# Command Handler not working (discord.js v14)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im trying to make a discord bot using node.js and ive come to this problem that it wont accept 1 line of scripts because something is not defined.

I tried to make a command handler and i am being rejcted with an error of:

```
C:\Users\Filip-PC\Desktop\Tadek\index.js:11
client.commands = new Collection();
                      ^

ReferenceError: Collection is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Filip-PC\Desktop\Tadek\index.js:11:23)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Here are my index.js scripts:

```
const {
    Client
} = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
    intents: 32767
});
const {
    Token
} = require("./config.json");

client.commands = new Collection();

require("./Handlers/Events")(client);

client.login(Token);
```

and here is my handler:

```
const { Perms } = require("../Validation/Permissions");
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const { glob } = require("glob");
const PG = promisify(glob);
const Ascii = require("ascii-table");

/**
 * @param {Client} client
 */
module.export = async (client) => {
    const Table = new Ascii("Command Loaded");

    CommandsArray = [];

    (await PG (`${process.cwd()}/Command/*/*.js`)).map(async (file) => {
        const command = require(file);

        if(!command.name)
        return Table.addRow(file.split("/")[7], "⛔ FAILED", "MISSING A NAME")

        if(!command.description)
        return Table.addRow(file.split("/")[7], "⛔ FAILED", "MISSING A NAME")

        if(command.permission) {
            if(Perms.includes(command.permission))
            command.defaultPermission = false;
            else
            return Table.addRow(file.split("/")[7], "⛔ FAILED", "PERMISSION IS INVALID")
        }

        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        CommandsArray.push(command);

        await Table.addRow(command.name, " SUCCESFUL");


    });

    console.log(Table.toString());

    //PERMISSION CHECKER

    client.on("ready", async () => {
        const MainGuild = await client.guilds.cache.get("1117802218595291216");

            const Roles = (commandName) => {
                const cmdPerms = CommandsArray.find((c)=> c.name === commandName).permission;
                if(!cmdPerms) return null;

                return MainGuild.roles.cache.filter((r) => r.permissions.has(cmdPerms));
            }
            
            const fullPermissions = command.reduce((accumulator, r) => {
                const roles = Roles(r.name);
                if(!roles) return accumulator;

                const permissions = roles.reduce((a, r) => {
                    return [...a, {id: r,id, type: "ROLES", permissions: true}]
                }, []);

                return [...accumulator, {id: r.id, permissions: true}]
            }, []);

            await MainGuild.commands.permissions.set({ fullPermissions })
        });
    });
}
```

This is really hard for me to solve since im a somewhat begginer (I just came back to coding)

If its possible i would really apreciate help!

Answer (score 0):

`Collection()` is not a standalone of JavaScript or node.js.

It is part of the `discord.js` library, so in order to fix this particular issue,

you need to require it:

```
const {
Client, Collection
} = require("discord.js");
```